# DataConversionWarning on sklearn Logistic Regression

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to perform a logistics regression in sklearn below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)

mod_data2 = mod_data.copy()

classifier.fit(mod_data2[['prob1_norm', 'prob2_norm']].values.reshape(-1,2), mod_data2['Success'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

But it is giving me the error message:

```
 DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
```

I have tried using .ravel() on the end of my input data but then it tells me I have the wrong dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `mod_data2['Success'].values.ravel()` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and rather than just giving me a warning it tells me 
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.46062633 0.39853439 0.46062633 ... 0.21442516 0.06186648 0.02173996].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 1):

[df.squeeze()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) should work. It converts a dataframe to a series and when I used it the warning conversion went away

y = mod_data2['Success'].squeeze()